# Displaying form errors in Phoenix 1.6

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following template code in a new Phoenix 1.6 project :

```
<%= form_for @changeset, @action, fn f -> %>
  <%= if @changeset.action do %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      <p>Invalid parameters</p>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= label f, :slug, class: "form-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :slug, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= error_tag f, :slug %>
  </div>
```

However the changeset errors are never displayed. The invalid parameters alert shows so the changeset action is not nil. There are form errors when I inspect the changeset.

Here is the controller code :

```
  def update(conn, params) do
    current_user = conn.assigns.current_user
    slug = Enum.join(params["slug"], "/")
    repo = RepositoryManager.get_repository_by_owner_and_slug(params["owner"], \
slug)
    if repo do
      org = repo.organisation
      if org && Enum.find(org.users, &(&1.id == current_user.id)) || repo.user_\
id == current_user.id do
        case RepositoryManager.update_repository(repo, params["repository"]) do
          {:ok, repo} ->
            conn
            |> redirect(to: Routes.repository_path(conn, :show, params["owner"]\
, Repository.splat(repo)))
          {:error, changeset} ->
            IO.inspect(changeset)
            conn
            |> assign(:action, Routes.repository_path(conn, :update, params["ow\
ner"], Repository.splat(repo)))
            |> assign(:changeset, changeset)
            |> assign_current_organisation(org)
            |> assign(:current_repository, repo)
            |> assign(:repo, repo)
            |> render("edit.html")
        end
      end
    else
      not_found(conn)
    end
  end
```

and the console output :

```
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.0ms idle=0.2ms
begin []
#Ecto.Changeset<
  action: :update,
  changes: %{
    slug: "plop/test/123",
    user: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :update, changes: %{}, errors: [],
     data: #Kmxgit.UserManager.User<>, valid?: true>
  },
  errors: [slug: {"has invalid format", [validation: :format]}],
  data: #Kmxgit.RepositoryManager.Repository<>,
  valid?: false
>
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.1ms
rollback []
[info] Sent 200 in 5ms
```

Comment: The code shown has no mention of changeset errors, why would you expect it to display them?

Comment: What is the purpose of `error_tag` then ?

Comment: If you check the source of your page, isn't it there but hidden by some CSS?

Comment: No, in the produced HTML nothing appears instead of `error_tag`.

Comment: This might help you investigating whats happening to your errors
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/form-bindings.html#phx-feedback-for

Comment: changesets without an :action don't trigger an error display.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is to generate an error changeset before the transaction failed, and then upgrade this error changeset with the second changeset errors. Fixed upstream in https://git.kmx.io/kmx.io/kmxgit/_commit/9b1772752e1573582087e91fca1b947b3020f2aa